# Why one CSS class overrides other?

Tags: css, vue.js

I am working on a Vue.js project that uses Vuetify and vue-flash-message. I am trying to set warning message background to 'blueviolet' by editing its style:

```
.flash__message.warning {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border-color: #ef9e3b;
}
```

but there is '.warning' class in Vuetify that overrides it, see the screenshot [image: screenshot].

I wonder if anyone can explain what technique is used here. And what is the right way to make the message background 'blueviolet' in this situation?

Comment: `!important` like inline style, try `.warning.flash__message { background: #color !important; ...`

Comment: The styles have `!important`, meaning they will overwrite any others. https://medium.com/markuptips/css-is-important-960a9921e454

Comment: CSS rules with `!important` will override any other CSS rules, including the ones you have just written. You need to remove the `warning` class for your own rules to take effect.

Comment: `!important` is a "feature" of CSS.  Please search for it's usages and intention.

Comment: I don't know which duplicate to redirect you to; 2 main CSS rules can apply here: the use of `!important` or the fact that if one rule comes after another in the document, it overrides the first (depending on where each of your rules are declared, removing the `!important` could not be enough)

Comment: Use of the `!important;` declaration causes the normal CSS specificity rules to break. Use this with caution. Here are some resources for you to review: [MDN - CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), [CSS Precedence](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/css/precedence.html), [Understanding Style Precedence in CSS: Specificity - Inheritance - and the Cascade](https://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)...

Comment: Yes, thank you guys! It is !important.

Comment: @HamSter, Yes, it is !important. Is there a difference between .warning.flash__message and .flash__message.warning?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky, No! The differences between `.warning.flash__message` and `.flash__message.warning` are not!

Comment: @HamSter did you mean there is no difference? (вы имели ввиду что нет разницы?)

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky, да) я имею ввиду, что нет разницы если поменять местами классы, все это будет один и тот же элемент )

Comment: @HamSter А есть разница .flash__message.warning и .warning ?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky, только в "весе", а элемент тот же. Почитайте статью yoksel там, вроде, все очень просто написано.

Comment: @HamSter понял (clear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is your second class which is telling the browser to set the background to yellow as the !important tag on the end of each property. !important tells the browser to override any other styles that overlap classes. You need to:

A) Remove the important from the yellow styles and apply them to the purple

B) Remove the yellow styles all together.

Option A will seem more 'logical' but it depends what environment your working in and how your code etiquette applies to your project. I prefer to keep everything simple and just remove the intrusive css and try and use less !importants in web projects.

For more information on the !important utility visit this helpful blog post: [!Important Utility information](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Hope this helps.